# iOS Firebase + Fabric Beta Crashylitics Not Reporting Issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I've just recently installed Fabric to a project which already had Firebase installed and suddenly Crashyltics has stopped working. It's not included within the 'Fabric.with([])' call on AppDelegate.swift but I wondered if Fabric and Firebase were cancelling out Crashyltics. I'm using Fabric for it's Beta option and everything else is inside Firebase.

1. I can force a crash inside the app - But not getting anything reported in either Dashboard.
2. My run Script Phase is also correct.
3. My Debug is DWARF with DYSIM.
4. Cleared derived data etc.
5. Firebase is called after Fabric inside AppDelegate.

Thanks

Comment: Can you see your bug reports in fabric dashboard?

Comment: Nothing gets shown in Fabric

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to link your firebase and fabric apps.
Go to https://fabric.io/firebase_migration/status, click on link apps and select the apps to link (the one on fabric and the corresponding app on firebase)

Comment: Yes the linked app is showing from the migration page.

Answer (score -1):

Do you upload your dSYM to Firebase/Crashlytics? If not it can be the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I upload each time its required.